# How to fit text in a rectangle in an image using python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i'm currently working on a project in which i need to make text in a specific rectangle (with varing height and width) in an image, and the font needs to be verdana if possible

I spent hour looking for ways to do that, but i couldn't find a way to do it which handled text wrapping while also using the biggest font size possible

What's an good way to get the text to fit inside a rectangle with text wrapping and without needing to lucky guess the font size?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually split the text to wrap it before adding it to the image.
This is the code I use:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

x,y = (10,10) # define start position of text
# select font file and size (Impact and size 30 in this case)
font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf', 30)
# open your image
img = Image.open("target_image.jpg")
# apply text warping
width = 1080
img_w = img.size[0]
img_h = img.size[1]
wpercent = (width/float(img_w))
hsize = int((float(img_h)*float(wpercent)))
rmg = img.resize((width,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
lines = text_wrap(text, font, rmg.size[0]-x)
line_height = font.getsize('hg')[1]

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(rmg)
for line in lines:
    draw = black_outline(draw,font,line,x,y)
    y = y + line_height    # update y-axis for new line
rmg.save('new_image.jpg')
rmg.show()
```

Comment: This does wrap the text, but you must still guess what font size to use